# how to depend a fat jar (jar-with-dependencies) by maven

Tags: maven, jar-with-dependencies

the jar I have to depend displayed in maven repo is something like:

```
aaa/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
-- aaa-0.1.0-20231216.113327-1.jar
-- aaa-0.1.0-20231216.113327-1.pom
-- aaa-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I add the dependency in the POM like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxx.yyy</groupId>
            <artifactId>aaa</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

It's ok to load the POM, but something error when I compile it

*The POM for com.xxx.yyy:aaa:jar:jar-with-dependencies:1.1.0.33-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available*

In my local repo, I can find 'aaa-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar' already downloaded, but missing 'aaa-0.1.0--SNAPSHO.jar' and 'aaa-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'

I wonder how to use jar-with-dependencies correctly

Comment: Please show your full pom file and also the output log... also can you give more information which Maven version, JDK version etc. you are using?

Comment: It is usual a bad idea to use a jar-with-dependencies as dependency. It is better to use the original JAR.

Comment: Sorry no. Fat jars are meant for execution,  not as dependencies.